# how to differentiate between two submit buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC and already working on a task that has become overwhelming, trying to figure out how to render a log in form from a partial view, inside a jQuery accordion tab, without submitting the entire page.

I am including an image of my page.

Your Order Tab
[image: this is the page I am working on]

Complete Order Tab
[image]

The first tab: "Your Order" contains on the right side a small log in form with a button that read "Sign In".

The fifth tab: "Complete Order" contains a button "Complete Order"

When I click the button on the first tab to Sign In, the code that executes is the code for Complete Order button, and that causes many errors, because all the information collected on subsequent tabs is not there as when Complete Order gets clicked.

I would like to ask for help, to figure out a way to separate the events of these buttons, and be able to do a log in without running code that is part of other event.

I am not sure how to approach to this, this is my first time working with this architecture.

If I could get help on how to execute the log in method, and just display a simple div displaying "success! that would help me a lot.

Thank you much!

**CODE EDIT AFTER RECOMMENDATIONS**

The jQuery:

```
        function ShoppingCartLogin() {
        $("#Email").val();
        var userid = $("#YourOrder_MainLoginEmail").val();
        //var userid = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
        var password = $("#YourOrder_MainLoginPassword").val();
        //var password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
        alert(userid);
        var url = "/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCartLogin";
        $("#btnLogin").val('Sign In');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { userId: userid, pass: password },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    alert("Successfull login.");
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid user id and password.");
                }
                $(".YourOrder_MainLoginEmail").attr({ 'value': '' });
                $(".YourOrder_MainLoginPassword").attr({ 'value': '' });
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
        $("#btnlogin").val('Sign In');
    }
```

The PartialView markup

```
<div class="YourOrder__inputEmail">
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "YourOrder_MainLoginEmail", placeholder = "Email    
Address", @id = "YourOrder_MainLoginEmail" })
</div>
<div>
<div>
Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "YourOrder_MainLoginPassword", placeholder =      
"Password", @id = "YourOrder_MainLoginPassword" })
</div>
</div>
```

The controller code:

```
 public ActionResult ShoppingCartLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {
                var user = (from u in db.Users where u.Email == model.UserName && u.Password == model.Password && u.IsActive select u).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    return View(model);
                }

                List<string> roles = new List<string>();
                if (user.IsAdmin)
                {
                    roles.Add("Admin");
                }
                if (user.IsOrdersAdmin)
                {
                    roles.Add("Orders");
                }
                if (user.IsStoreAdmin)
                {
                    roles.Add("Stores");
                }

                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.ID.ToString(), model.RememberMe);
                var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                    1,                              // version
                    user.ID.ToString(),             // user name
                    DateTime.Now,                   // created
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(90),    // expires
                    model.RememberMe,               // persistent?
                    string.Join(",", roles)          // can be used to store roles
                    );

                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

                var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            }

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

When the code gets executed, LoginModel has null its propoerties UserName, Password although there are values in the textboxes.

The code goes to:

```
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For separating two button, put two different id of two buttons, assume button id of tab 0( Your order) as btnYourOrder and tab 5(Complete order) button id as btnCompleteOrder then you write two jquery click events `$("#btnYourOrder").click(function(){<Your Code>});` and `$("#btnCompleteOrder").click(function(){<Your Code>});` and now whatever you want to execute you can put in their button events.

For executing partial view(not full postback) you can use below code

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url: <Your partial View URL>,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'text/html',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#divOrders").html(data);                  
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                }
            }
            );
```

divOrders--> Put one div with id divOrders where you want to show the partial view data.

If you want any other help or if you have not understood let me know, i will happy to help you.

Thanks
Raviranjan

```
    Other options:
       Hi Nima: there are many options, Option 1: Change your controller method as 
        public ActionResult ShoppingCartLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) 
          --> public ActionResult ShoppingCartLogin(string userId, string pass, string returnUrl) 
        for  your current javascript/juery ajax call .

        option 2: Put your User Id, Password, and button(no submit):  
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("/ShoppingCartLogin", "ShoppingCart", new AjaxOptions { 
         UpdateTargetId =    "divSaveUsers", InsertionMode =InsertionMode.Replace, 
        OnSuccess = "onUserSaveSuccess", OnFailure = "onUserSaveFailure", HttpMethod = "POST" }, 
         new { @autocomplete = "off", @id = "frmuserdetails" }))
      {<br/>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()<br/>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true) <br/>
      <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSaveData" /><br/>
      }
        <br/>

    <script>
        $("#btnSaveData").click(function (event) {
            $("#frmuserdetails").submit();
        });<br/>

        </script>


        and keep your controller method as usual
```

Comment: @user3020641. I am using something similar to your recommendation, but when the controller code gets called, it is not receiving values. Please see the code addition I made with my most recent code. I am not understanding. I seem to get the values because I added alert(userid); and I can see the email value entered, in the alert box, but I do not understand why the C# code, the model is not receiving the values. Many thanks for your help. –

Comment: Hi Nima: there are many options,
Option 1: Change your controller method as 
public ActionResult ShoppingCartLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) --> public ActionResult ShoppingCartLogin(string userId, string pass, string returnUrl) for your current javascript/juery ajax call . option 2 in next post as it is long

Comment: Hi Nima : I have added the other option in my answer. For option 2 please add reference of unobtrusive jquery file, please check nd let me know if you have not understood

Comment: @user3020641. I am leaning to use option #1. changing the controller method to:  public ActionResult ShoppingCartLogin(string userId, string pass, string returnUrl) and the javascript:  function ShoppingCartLogin() {var userid = $(".YourOrder_MainLoginEmail").val(); var password = $(".YourOrder_MainLoginPassword").val();var url = "/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCartLogin";$.ajax({url: url,data: { userId: userid, pass: password },cache: false,type: "POST", success: function (data) {$("#YourOrder_Login").css('display', 'none');$("#divOrders").css('display', 'inline');},error: function (ex) {}});}

Comment: currently, after the method ShoppingCartLogin gets executed and returns success, I hide/ show divs. how difficult it is to replace the contents of the same area where the login form (partial view) were displayed, with the contents of another partial view, but without losing the successful login? is this clear?

Comment: Whatever i have understood that you want to replace the login partial view content to some new partial view after successful login: Take one div as parent of login partial view and after successful login use below code to replace : $.ajax({url: <Your partial View URL>,type: "POST",contentType: 'text/html',success: function (data) {$("#divOrders").html(data);},error: function (ex) {}}); where i am assuming parent div id is : divOrders. Let me know if you have any difficulty to understand.

Comment: If you found my answer as helpful then please accept this answer so other can also get benefit :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66521/discussion-between-itortu-and-user3020641).

Answer (score 1):

You can get button value in your post action argument by referencing button name,

For example if your button are defined like below,

```
<button type="submit" id="btnLogin" name="Command" value="Login">Login</button>
<button type="submit" id="btnCompleteOrder" name="Command" value="CompleteOrder">Complete Order</button>
```

you can get the button value and based on that choose which code you want to execute

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult PostAction(Model model,String Command) 
   { 
      If(Command == "Login")
          //Send them to login screen
          RedirectToAction("Login","LoginController");

      Else If(Command == "CompleteOrder")
        {
          //Complete your order processing
        }
      Else
        {
          //Some default action
        }

  Return View("Index");

   }
```

Comment: Glk.net I tried your recommendation, but when I click the SignIn button the value os string Command is null.

Comment: the `name` property of the both button should match that string parameter you're getting in your post action, in my example its set to `Command`

Comment: this solution works well. the submit buttons each with name="xyz" are going into the parameter list on server handler when POSTing the form. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use submit, use `<form action=''…` and declare a `loginForm()` function to jQuery `$.post` the credentials from those fields using a `<button onclick='loginForm()'>Submit </button>`

Comment: Hi MiiinimalLogic, I am open to try a different approach, would it be possible that you show me how this is done? I have no much jQuery/ ajax experience. I included the server side code if that helps.

Comment: Sure, just like I said:  1) Use your original form with a regular submit as usual but the second form doesn't have submit input type, instead a button with an onclick set to a javascript function that you define.  2) The javascript function you define will use jQuery's post method (ajax) check out the documentation on it.  Its super easy.  3) When you get the result from the post method, then use the redirect of javascript to complete the action.

Comment: Hi again, are the instructions on this link, sort of what you are recommending? http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/09/ajax-login-form-using-jquery-in-aspnet.html

Comment: Yea thats pretty much it, but instead of a 'successful login' message you'd redirect the page. Or have the controller portion of your MVC, if you're using one, redirect to the protected area.

Answer (score 0):

i had two buttons generated by php code and i wanted to know which button is clicked. i used them in same class. The php code is as follow

```
$class = "qdiv";
$type="button";
$click="ask(".$j.")";   //put variable to have a record of question asked

echo '<button id="'.$j.'" type="'.$type.'" class="'.$class.'" onclick="'.$click.'">'; 
echo $row['question'];
echo '</button>';
```

In the code above i gave separate id but by some reason the id was not readable by JavaScript (one reason i guess is that i asked id by class and one class had different ids) so i have onclick=ask(j) function and j return a unique number to differentiate which button is clicked.

the java script code is as follow.

```
function ask(qid) 
{
//var qid=document.getElementsByClassName("qdiv").id;
document.getElementById("divresult").innerHTML=qid;
}
```